# How to display a side nav menu with many sub-categories using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay I was wondering how can you use PHP and MySQL to create and display a side nav menu with many categories and sub-categories?

I just don't know where to begin coding the PHP code?

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="" title="">First Nested Link</a></li>
   <li><a href="" title="">First Nested Link</a></li>
   <li><a href="" title="">First Nested Link</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" title="">Second Nested Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Second Nested Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Second Nested Link</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="" title="">Third Nested Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="">Third Nested Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="">Third Nested Link</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="" title="">Fourth Nested Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="">Fourth Nested Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="">Fourth Nested Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="" title="">Third Nested Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="">Third Nested Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Second Nested Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Second Nested Link</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="" title="">First Nested Link</a></li>
   <li><a href="" title="">First Nested Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my MySQL tables.

```
* categories
      id | category_name | description
* sub_categories
      id | parent_id | category_name | description
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only need one table for your categories; just set the `parent_id` field to null for top-level categories.

As for actually generating the HTML, you can do something along these lines (pseudocode), where `$category_data` is the results of the query in a two-dimensional array and `$category_id` is the id of the parent category being generated.  To kick it off, use `$category_id = 0`

```
function print_category($category_data, $category_id)
{
    print "<ul>";
    foreach ($category_data as $category)
    {
        if ((integer)$category['parent_id'] == $category_id)
        {
            print "<li>" . $category['category_name'] . "</li>";
            print_category($category_data, $category['id']);
        }
    }
    print "</ul>";
}
```

You'll have to modify that for your own layout and table structure.  You can improve the performance (if you have a huge number of categories) by transforming the array into a three-dimensional array, `$category_data[parent_id][id][category_row]`.

Comment: Generating the faster array is actually simple enough to do it by default: `$ctg_data = array(); foreach ($rows as $row) { $ctg_data[$row['parent_id']][] = $row; }`. Then you can use `foreach ($ctg_data[$category_id] as $ctg)`.